# Premission denied to start session - PHP

Tags: php, session, tmp

I have the following error:

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(---temp\sess_u800qhordqngjf1c9mlspmb1c6, O_RDWR) failed:
>   Permission denied (13) in ---login.php on line 2
>       Warning: Unknown: open(---temp\sess_u800qhordqngjf1c9mlspmb1c6, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 
>       Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
>   (---\temp) in Unknown on line 0

instead the path displayed I wrote ---.

This error wasn't displayed until now (I'm on localhost).
I tried to find the solution on the web, but I can't figure what exactly should I do...

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, does that path exist? Does the webserver have permissions to it?

Comment: @Andrew Yes I think it exist...

Comment: a) check the  session.save_path in you php.ini file
b) check do you have permissions to write in given folder
c) check that you have free space in this device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `php.ini` file it is specifying the `session.save_path` to be `---\temp`.

That means one of the following is your problem:

1) That path does not exist
2) That path is not writable

As a solution, you have three options:

1) Make the path exist
2) Make the path writable
3) Change it to another path